# swing: UI for a countdown timer

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, timer

I need a variable countdown timer for between 1-10 seconds, that can be stopped and restarted. What's a good set of UI elements to use for this? I need something intuitive that uses a fairly small amount of screen real estate, comparable to a normal-sized JButton. A windup kitchen egg timer would be the best physical analogy:

[image]

**NOTE**: I know *how* to implement timers and restart them, I just need to figure out what UI elements to use.

**NOTE 2**: I need a *variable* countdown timer. If the user wants 1 second, I want a 1 second timer. If the user wants an 8.2 second timer, I want an 8.2 second timer.  The kitchen timer above is simple, the user just turns it to a certain amount and lets it go.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use a `JProgressBar` that starts off "full" and empties as the time decreases?  You overlay the remaining time in seconds over the bar, therefore avoiding using additional screen real estate.

Comment: That's an indicator. I need a way to both display and set.

Comment: (although +1 since it does have aesthetic appeal as an indicator)

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly simple... Labels and buttons should be fine.. Here are some examples

[image]
<sub>(source: [itblogs.info](http://www.itblogs.info/img/android_stopwatch.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [softpedia.com](http://handheld.softpedia.com/images/software/thumbs/Stopwatch-Android-thumb.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [leancrew.com](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/images/iphone-stopwatch-laps.png))</sub>

Comment: and how do I set it? I really would just like something as simple as an egg timer.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "set it"

Comment: A JLabel and 2 JButtons under it or on the sides should be enough. The rest is just styling

Comment: set it = decide to set the timer to 10 seconds or 1 second or 5 seconds.

Comment: When the set button is pressed drop down menu appears with those times. So all together it would take 2 clicks. For more cutomization set of JSpinners can replace the time label just for setting time.

Answer (score 1):

For a short term solution I used a JSlider... I add an ActionListener to its BoundedRangeModel, and set my timer when there is a change and the BoundedRangeModel.getValueIsAdjusting() returns false. When my timer counts down but is not yet expired and the BoundedRangeModel.getValueIsAdjusting() returns false, I call BoundedRangeModel.setValue().

Not too happy with it but it kinda does what I want.

Comment: For entertainment, you can dress up the `SliderUI`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898259

Answer (score 1):

A (ridiculously) simple solution: if you don't need too much graphical flair, just use a single JButton that displays the seconds remaining when the timer is running.  When the timer's off, it displays "Start"; clicking it will begin the countdown.  You could then stop (or pause) it by clicking when the timer is running.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a `JSpinner` for the setting; a `javax.swing.Timer` for the counting; and a single button, labelled "Start" or "Stop" as a function of the `Timer` state. Almost anything would do for display, but @Adamski's `JProgressBar` idea has appeal.